# how to replace the particular column value using python

Tags: python, pandas

[Input Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZWHz.png)

[output data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7wj3.png) in output, some particular column should be replace and other value of other column should be repeated

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the problem being solved here, and if the apparent pattern hold good for other newer values, if any, in the input dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your input dataframe has column names as col1, col2, col3 and col4, the required output dataframe can be generated as follows:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'])
for i,j,k,l in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3'], df['col4']):
    if 'NTR' in i:
        j = 19.0
        k = 0.0
        i.replace('NTR', 'NT')
        if int(i[-2:]) % 2 == 0:
            l = 720
        else:
            l = 710
    if 'PHB' in i:
        j = 126.0
        k = 0.0
        if int(i[-2:]) % 2 == 0:
            l = 630
        else:
            l = 620
    if 'GHY' in i:
        j = 62.0
        k = 0.0
        if int(i[-2:]) % 2 == 0:
            l = 750
        else:
            l = 740
    if 'TRP' in i:
        i.replace('TRP', 'TR')
        j = 50.0
        k = 2.0
        if int(i[-2:]) % 2 == 0:
            l = 130
        else:
            l = 120
    upd = {'Name': i,'Val1' : j, 'Val2' : k,'Val3' : l}
    output_df = output_df.append(upd, ignore_index = True)
```

Where `df` is your input dataframe and `output_df` is your resultant dataframe.